# How to parse multipart/mixed SIP invite message body using osip.dll(osip library)?

Tags: sip

The 'multipart/mixed' type message body consists of SDP message and another type. I need to parse and decode using osip

Comment: Have you tried something already? If so, please post code and SIP message example. You can check documentation https://www.antisip.com/doc/osip2/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

The bodies are in `osip_message_t` struct field `bodies`, so code around the lines:

```
 osip_message_t *sip;
 osip_message_init(&sip);
 err = osip_message_parse(sip, msg, len);
 if (err != 0) { ... }
 ...
 while (!osip_list_eol(&sip->bodies, body_index)) {
  current_body = (osip_body_t *) osip_list_get(&sip->bodies, body_index);
  /*here insert code to parse bodies or for SDP use sdp_message_parse*/
```